# Автоматизация инвйтинга вконтакте

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, веб-программирование, автоматизация

в гpyппe вк 10000 чeлoвeк, нa мepoпpиятиe я приглacил вcex, a возможность приглашения  нe oтключeна тoлькo y 570 чeлoвeк.

как мне следующий раз отправлять приглашения на мероприятие не всем, а только тем 570, которые были приглашены на предыдущее?

чем простеньким можно это автоматизировать? Imacros не подходит, т.к. при приглашении кого либо на мероприятие - поиск можно производить только среди друзей, а среди участников группы он не работает

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно автоматизировать поиск участников с допуском к приглашениям, либо автоматизировать саму рассылку? Для автоматизации есть метод [groups.invite](https://vk.com/dev/groups.invite), но Вы рискуете аккаунтом, ведь это будет расценено, как "СПАМ" и Ваш аккаунт будет заблокирован за рассылку после 15-20 приглашений. 
Для подобных целей нужно то, что имитирует работу браузера, а не работает через API.

В плане получения ID ничего порекомендовать не могу, кроме как постараться получить ID тех, кто ещё не приняли приглашение с помощью [groups.getInvitedUsers](https://vk.com/dev/groups.getInvitedUsers).